# What does `cluster_security_group_id` do in the Terraform EKS module?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

From [the documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest?tab=inputs),

> Description: Existing security group ID to be attached to the cluster. Required if `create_cluster_security_group` = `false`

I have set `create_cluster_security_group = false` and assigned a security group (let's call it `data-sg`) I've created elsewhere to the `cluster_security_group_id` input.  This security group is also attached to a couple RDS instances, and `data-sg` has a rule allowing all ingress within itself:

```
module "data_sg" {
 source  = "terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws"
 version = "4.9.0"

 name   = "data-sg"
 vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id

 ingress_with_self = [
   {
     description = "All ingress within data-sg"
     rule        = "all-all"
     self        = true
   }
 ]
...
}
```

Yet, pods in my EKS cluster cannot reach the RDS instances.

It seems that the pods are not within the `data-sg` security group, which begs the first question:

1. What is `cluster_security_group_id` actually used for?

Assuming this security group isn't actually being used in the way that I thought, it begs a second question:

2. What security group do I need to allow RDS-type ingress from in the `data-sg` security group?

Seems like there's an output from the EKS module called `cluster_primary_security_group_id`, but adding this

```
    ingress_with_source_security_group_id = [
      {
        description              = "RDS ingress from EKS cluster"
        from_port                = 5432
        to_port                  = 5432
        source_security_group_id = var.cluster_primary_security_group_id
      }
    ]
```

to the `module "aws_sg" { ...` above also does not allow me to connect to RDS from EKS pods.

Comment: How do Pods connect to the RDS, i.e., is it an application running inside the Pod which should be accessing the RDS instance?

Comment: @MarkoE Specifically, it's a Helm deployment of Apache Airflow that's configured to use one of the RDS instances for the Airflow DB.  It runs some migrations on deployment.  But I can exec into the pod and try to run `psql` commands, and I see the same thing as the migration pod reports: `connection to server at "my-rds.blah.us-east-1" (12.23.34.45), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?`

Comment: Could it be that some IAM permissions are missing?

Comment: @MarkoE Hmm.  IAM permissions for what, exactly?  When it's an IAM issue, the error usually makes that obvious.  This is a PostgreSQL connection timeout error, not an AWS API error, which is what made me think it's a misconfigured security group rule.

Comment: Yeah, just thinking out loud.